# Add ubuntu repository command fails to run

Tags: 20.04, kubernetes

Sorry for the newb question. I'm trying to add a repository to my ubuntu machine:

```
 $ sudo curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key add -
 <<EOF >/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list
deb https://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main
EOFE: This command can only be used by root.
(23) Failed writing body
$ cat <<EOF >/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list
> deb https://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main
> EOF^C
```

But the command is 'breaking' in half when I try to run it by pasting it into the terminal. I'm having trouble with the `cat EOF` part of the command.

This is the command that I want to run:

```
sudo curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key add -
cat <<EOF >/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list
deb https://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main
EOF
```

This is on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa).

```
cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS"
```

How can I get this working?

Comment: Not available for releases over xenial https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/dists  there is no folder for focal there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [This command can only be used by root](https://askubuntu.com/questions/845534/this-command-can-only-be-used-by-root) You don't need `sudo` with `curl` but with `apt-key`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you should be using 2 distinct commands. `cat` and `apt-key` commands are distinct.

Further, the `cat` command serves only to automatically create the proper `sources.list` file.  You can just copy-paste the text into the specified file if you have access to any sort of text editor.

Just run the `cat` command separately from the `apt-key` command and you'll be golden.

Comment: Ok thanks, that worked!